# Issue with navbar margin on hover their links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an issue with Bootstrap Navbar, I am trying to do the same navbar as Twitter, once you hover on the links, a little border-bottom appears, I reach that behavior already, but once that border appears the height of the Navbar changes. I recorded [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2H503VRGRk&feature=youtu.be) for you to understant and also I prepared [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/KwoLaQ); the weird thing here is that when you hover tha Logo part, the height of the Navbar does not change.

here is my css:

```
.capilleira-navbar{
  background: getColor(snow);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.1);
  a {
    color: getColor(night);
  }
  a:hover, a:focus {
    background: getColor(snow) !important;
    color: lighten(getColor(red), 10%);
    border-bottom: 4px solid lighten(getColor(red), 10%);
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
}
```

and here my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar capilleira-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/lines">LOGO</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#/lines">Sports <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Poker</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Casino</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Horses</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using border use box-shadow, it doesn't have this problem.

For your a:hover in css use this instead

```
 a:hover, a:focus {
    background: getColor(snow) !important;
    color: red;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px 0px red;//this <--
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

What RuteNL said...
or you could use fixed height

```
a {
    color: getColor(night);
    height:50px;
  }
```

Comment: This is the right answer, try to explain why this works . Logo works because has a fixed height of 50px and the property `box-sizing:border-box` making the border inside that height. ..... since the links on the menu doesn't have any fixed height then the box-sizing has no effect and the border is just added to the actual height.